# a = 90.8. b = 90.6, a-b == 0.2 is False? R issue

Tags: r, if-statement, math, equation, radix

I just encounter a very weird issue. Following is the code

```
a <- 90.8
b <- 90.6
a - b == 0.2
```

returns `FALSE`

Any ideas???

Comment: because of floating point.  You can check `print(a-b, digits=20)#
[1] 0.20000000000000284`

Comment: Yeah, that's true. So how can I fix that? I need to write an if condition on the difference.

Comment: Well,  what condition do you need?  Presumably,  it is not that the difference is exactly 0.2.

Comment: Use `all.equal`.

Comment: What if I want to use inequality? For example, `90.8 - 90.6 <= 0.2`, which will give `FALSE`

Comment: `is.less <- function(x, y, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) x - y < tol; is.less(90.8 - 90.6, 0.2)` returns `TRUE`. Same for `<=` or `>`. If you want equality use `abs(x - y) < tol`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you!

Comment: `isTRUE(all.equal(a - b, 0.2))` is what you should be using

Comment: @rawr That's the standard way but the reason why the function in my comment is that `all.equal` is not vectorized and sometimes we need a logical vector. Note that I use the same default tolerance as `all.equal`.